# How to use DbContext.FindAsync() read text[] in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, crud

When I use **Edit** function,I find it can't read data which type is string[].
When I use DbContext.FindAsync(ID), the data of MailReceiver will show  **System.String[]**.
Can someone tell me what happened?
It is my context

```
public partial class GatewaySettingDevice
{
    public string GatewayId { get; set; }
    public string Protocol { get; set; }
    public int Pid { get; set; }
    public string SmtpServer { get; set; }
    public string[] MailReceiver { get; set; }
}
```

It is the action of edit

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var gatewaySettingDevice = await _context.GatewaySettingDevices.FindAsync(id);
        if (gatewaySettingDevice == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(gatewaySettingDevice);
    }
```

Comment: So you're saying that what `FindAsync` is returning is an array of strings? Rather than a single `GatewaySettingDevice` object?

Comment: Actually FindAsync just return word ,and word is System.String[]....

Comment: I'm confused. Is `FindAsync` a method you wrote? If so, can you provide the source code?

Comment: I have re-read your question. Are you saying, "I was expecting the data type to be `string[]` and instead it's `System.String[]`: why?"  I can answer that: `System.String` is the formal name for the data type `string`. So any data type that involves `string`, like `string[]` or `List<string>`, is really of `System.String`:  `System.String[]`, `List<System.String>`.

Comment: In other words -- assuming I've correctly understood your question -- nothing is wrong. The tools are just using the formal names for the data types rather than the informal, C# names. 

Comment: If that's NOT what you're asking, and you're asking about getting the string `System.String[]` in a variable instead of actual data, than what's probably happened is that for some reason the `ToString()` method was called on an object, and the object happened to be a string array. For most classes, the default result of `ToString()` is the name of the type, i.e. "System.String[]" for a string array.

Comment: Yes, I mean that. But I have no idea about how to solve the reason of **ToString**.

Comment: Can you give me some advice how should I do ?